# How to correctly specify all available GPUs on a single workstation machine with snakemake?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, snakemake, multi-gpu

Suppose I have 36 jobs and I want to use 2 GPUs on my workstation

Following [this tutorial](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources) the following configuration does not use 2 GPUs simultaneously when running `rule a`

```
rule a:
    output:
        "test.txt"
    resources:
        nvidia_gpu=2
    shell:
        "somecommand ..."
```

Adding `--set-resource-scopes gpus=global` also does not change the behavior

Could someone give an example of how to enable using multiple GPUs on the same machine when running snakemake?

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on how you tell `somecommand` to use two gpus.  Snakemake will effectively throttle how many instances of `rule a` are run simultaneously.  If you specify `--resources nvidia_gpu=2` then only one `rule a` job will run at a time; other jobs without gpu requirements will still be eligible.  It is then up to you to tell somecommand there are two GPUs to use.  The use of resource scope doesn't really apply here since you are running everything on your workstation.

Consider updating with:

- more info on somecommand
- How you are invoking snakemake
- What does "does not use 2 GPUs simultaneously when running rule a" mean?  No GPU usage, more than one instance of rule a, etc.

Comment: "If you specify --resources nvidia_gpu=2 then only one rule a job will run at a time; " why is that? I assume if I specify 2 GPUS, then two jobs can run simultaneously?

Comment: You say that the rule requires 2 gpus in its resource directive `nvidia_gpu=2`.  If the rule only uses one, you should set the resource to `nvidia_gpu=1` and invoke with `snakemake --resources nvidia_gpu=2`.  That says the *rule* uses 1 gpu but overall you have 2 available and 2 jobs will run at once.

Comment: should I also specify snakemake --cores 2 to match the number of GPUs?